# VBA downloading files from IE: Second popup appears after clicking "Save"

Tags: excel, vba

I am automating a process where I have to download files from a website in internet explorer I have the following code which clicks the "Save" button once the download pops up.

```
Sub thing()

'Find download message and click Save to download file
Dim o As IUIAutomation
Set o = New CUIAutomation
Dim Completed As String
Dim h As Long
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim html As HTMLDocument

Sleep 1000
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
Do
    h = ie.hwnd
    h = FindWindowEx(h, 0, "Frame Notification Bar", vbNullString)

    If h <> 0 Then
        Dim count As Long
        count = 0
        Exit Do
    Else
        Sleep 100
        count = count + 1
    End If
Loop

Dim e As IUIAutomationElement
Set e = o.ElementFromHandle(ByVal h)

Dim iCnd As IUIAutomationCondition
Set iCnd = o.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, "Save")

Dim Button As IUIAutomationElement
Set Button = e.FindFirst(TreeScope_Subtree, iCnd)

Sleep 1000

Do
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim InvokePattern As IUIAutomationInvokePattern
    Set InvokePattern = Button.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_InvokePatternId)

    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        On Error GoTo 0
        Exit Do
    Else
        Sleep 100
        count = count + 1
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
Loop

InvokePattern.Invoke

Do
    Sleep 1000
    Completed = DownloadComplete()
    If Completed = "Yes" Then
        Exit Do
    Else
    End If
Loop

SendMessage h, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0

End Sub
```

However when I run this automation at home, sometimes the following popup appears after clicking "Save":
[image: DialogBox]

How should I tell VBA to click "Retry" if this button pops up?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

As this is the second popup notification bar, you cannot invoke your `AutomationElement` which is `Button` in your code because there is no "save" button to find in IE.

You need to reset your `AutomationCodition` `iCnd` to "Retry" and find the button to invoke it. `Button` will be `Nothing` if you cannot find the save button.

```
While Not filefound
    If Dir(file_path) <> "" Then filefound = True
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

    Dim o As IUIAutomation
    Dim e As IUIAutomationElement
    Set o = New CUIAutomation

    Dim h As Long
    h = ie.Hwnd
    h = FindWindowEx(h, 0, "Frame Notification Bar", vbNullString)

    If h <> 0 Then
        On Error Resume Next

        Set e = o.ElementFromHandle(ByVal h)
        Dim iCnd As IUIAutomationCondition
        Set iCnd = o.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, "Save")

        Dim Button As IUIAutomationElement
        Set Button = e.FindFirst(TreeScope_Subtree, iCnd)
        If Button Is Nothing Then
            Set iCnd = o.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, "Retry")
            Set Button = e.FindFirst(TreeScope_Subtree, iCnd)
        End If

        Dim InvokePattern As IUIAutomationInvokePattern
        Set InvokePattern = Button.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_InvokePatternId)
        InvokePattern.Invoke

        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
Wend
```